# VBscript and CMD writing into a text file

Tags: shell, text, command-line, vbscript

I am writing a script that executes and write everything to the file

here is example,

I stored the complete command in the variable 'Command' ,

```
Command = "ftp ftp.xyz.com 21 " & vbCRLF
```

and then executing it in command prompt,

```
shell.Run "%comspec% /c FTP " & Command & " > " & E:/abc.txt, 0, TRUE
```

but when this program execute it won't write anything to the text file because this is an incomplete command, this command on execution prompt user to input username and password of FTP,

how can i do this , that my programm automatically input username and password when prompt and then write everything to file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run FTP using an unattended script.  (Try `ftp /?` and look at the -s switch.)

It looks like this:

```
Const HOSTNAME = "ftp.myserver.com"
Const USERNAME = "Login"
Const PASSWORD = "password"

Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set objFso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFso.CreateTextFile("session.txt")

With objFile
    .WriteLine "USER username"
    .WriteLine "password"
    .WriteLine "cd /public_html/"  ' continue adding commands like this
    .Close
End With

strOutput = "C:\somefilepath\output.txt"
strCommand = "%systemroot%\System32\ftp.exe -s:session.txt > " & strOutput
strCommand = WshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings(strCommand)
WshShell.Run strCommand, 0, vbTrue

objFso.DeleteFile "session.txt", vbTrue
```

You can read more in my article [Using FTP in WSH](http://www.aspfree.com/c/a/Windows-Scripting/Using-FTP-in-WSH/) on ASP Free.  I also answered a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9335200/why-do-we-need-generate-a-temporary-file-when-remote-uploading-to-ftp).

Comment: I guess there is a typo in the line `strCommand = WshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings(strFTP)`. strFtp is undefined.